# Fixing Missing Dependencies while building LineageOS 19.0/AOSP 12

Tags: android, arm, lineageos

I am trying to build Lineage 19.0 on a VPS running Fedora 34 Workstation. It has 8GB RAM and 20GB Swap. It is virtualized in KVM.

It had done all the other work correctly and I have doubled-check if I am leaving out on any dependencies. I had also recloned the hardware/ril path using https://github.com/LineageOS/android_hardware_ril/tree/lineage-19.0/ but it also didn't work.

This is the error.

```
[ 99% 1244/1245] finishing build rules ...
FAILED: 
hardware/ril/reference-ril/Android.mk: error: "libreference-ril (SHARED_LIBRARIES android-arm) missing libril (SHARED_LIBRARIES android-arm)" 
You can set ALLOW_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES=true in your environment if this is intentional, but that may defer real problems until later in the build.
hardware/ril/rild/Android.mk: error: "rild (EXECUTABLES android-arm) missing libril (SHARED_LIBRARIES android-arm)" 
You can set ALLOW_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES=true in your environment if this is intentional, but that may defer real problems until later in the build.
build/make/core/main.mk:1122: error: exiting from previous errors.
21:03:21 ckati failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (02:24 (mm:ss)) ####
```

ANSWER GIVEN BELOW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer:

First, ensure if you have a Samsung device that you have the latest Samsung hardware files.

Secondly, just throw in `ALLOW_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES=true` in your `BoardConfig.mk`